# jQuery read values from a html cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering what is the correct way to read values from a html table in jQuery?
Here is my HTML code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td id="final">[['1.48E+02', '1.79E+03', '2.16E+04', '2.61E+05', '3.15E+06', '3.81E+07', '4.60E+08', '5.56E+09', '6.72E+10', '8.12E+11'], ['1.20E+01', '1.48E+02', '1.79E+03', '2.16E+04', '2.61E+05', '3.15E+06', '3.81E+07', '4.60E+08', '5.56E+09', '6.72E+10']]</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jquery selector:

```
var s1 = $.parseJSON($('#final').text());
// I have tried .val(), .html(), but those did not work.
```

## However, if my HTML is written in this way, then the jquery code works:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td id="final">[[148.0, 1788.0, 21604.0, 261036.0, 3154036.0, 38109468.0, 460467652.0, 5563721292.0, 67225123156.0, 812265199164.0], [12.0, 148.0, 1788.0, 21604.0, 261036.0, 3154036.0, 38109468.0, 460467652.0, 5563721292.0, 67225123156.0]]</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Can anyone help me with my jquery code for the first HTML situation? Thanks!

Comment: Your JSON string isn't a valid json string, quotes must be double quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just try using eval:

```
var s1 = eval($('#final').text());
```

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/dVJVD/)

I find eval isn't too bad as long as you control the content that you put in the eval.

[The Eval Function.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)

Oh and also, please note if you don't wanna use that, remember than in JSON you can't use the single quote or it wont parse. You can always check for valid JSON here: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com. It will tell you all the errors in your JSON

Comment: Your Welcome, always love to help in the simplest way!

Answer (score 1):

That's because `[['1.48E+02', '1.79E+03', '2.16E+04', '2.61E+05', '3.15E+06', '3.81E+07', '4.60E+08', '5.56E+09', '6.72E+10', '8.12E+11'], ['1.20E+01', '1.48E+02', '1.79E+03', '2.16E+04', '2.61E+05', '3.15E+06', '3.81E+07', '4.60E+08', '5.56E+09', '6.72E+10']]` isn't JSON, you have to use `"` to represent strings, without the single quotes they are numbers. See http://json.org

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to convert them to numbers using jquery?

Comment: @tao.hong so you want to use the original format and get an array of number arrays?

Comment: Yes, I need to take values in the single quote. I might take Shawn31313's suggestion. Also, thanks for pointing out my mistake!